# Simplify the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{h_i}{2}(f(x_{i-1})+f(x_i)) +\frac{h_i^2}{12}((f'(x_{i-1})-f'(x_i)) $ $x_i$ equidistant

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Consider the interval $[a,b]$ with the nodes $a = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = b$. Let  $f \in C^1([a,b]) $ be a function.

Consider $$ Q_{[a,b]}(f) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{h_i}{2}(f(x_{i-1})+f(x_i)\right) +\frac{h_i^2}{12}((f'(x_{i-1})-f'(x_i))  $$ with $h_i = x_i - x_{i-1} $.

*Remark* : ( $Q_{[a,b]}(f)$ is quadrature formula for $\int_a^b f(x)dx $ )

**To do**: Simplify $Q_{[a,b]}(f)$ for equidistant nodes $x_i$.

*My work so far* :

We have equidistant nodes $x_i$. So $x_i = a + i\frac{(b-a)}{n}$.  We get that $h_i = \frac{(b-a)}{n}$ for all $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.  So:

\begin{align}
& Q_{[a,b]}(f) = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{(\frac{(b-a)}{n})}{2}(f(x_{i-1})+f(x_i)\right) +\frac{\left(\frac{(b-a)}{n}\right)^2}{12}(f'(x_{i-1})-f'(x_i)) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{(b-a)}{2n} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n((f(x_{i-1})+f(x_i)) +\frac{b-a}{6n}(f'(x_{i-1})-f'(x_i)) \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{(b-a)}{2n} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n(f(x_{i-1})+f(x_i)) + \left(\frac{b-a}{6n}(f'(a)-f'(b))\right)\right).
\end{align}

Here I'm stuck. I tried to simplify $f(x_{i-1})+f(x_i)$ but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n(f(x_{i-1})+f(x_i))
&=\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_{i-1})+\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(x_{i})+\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\\
&=f(x_0)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f(x_{i})+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f(x_i)+f(x_n)\\
&=f(x_0)+f(x_n)+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f(x_{i})\\
\end{array}
$